# AJAX HTTP-POST-Request - Saving JSON responses

Tags: json, ajax, api, post, http-post

I want to make a HTTP-POST-Request with AJAX to call a JSON API. So, the API should return a response in JSON. I can see on the console of the API, that the request is successful. But the problem is, that no data or status is returned, or that I can't use it with JQuery. Here is my function:

```
$.post("http://api-adress/controller",
    {
            email: input_mail,
            password: input_pw
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert(data);
        alert(status);
    }, 'json');
```

I guess the problem is that the response from the Server does not get saved in the variables data and status correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change a little bit your code like below:

```
var dataString = {
     email: input_mail,
     password: input_pw
}

    $.post("http://api-adress/controller", dataString, function (result) {

})
      .done(function (result) {
           //Here is your result. You must parseJSON if it is json format
           var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

       })
       .fail(function () {
              //use this if you need it
       })
```

Also make sure that you get the response through firebug in console tab. You can check there what you post, what you get etc.